# Could the cosmic background radiation solve the Fermi Paradox?

Tags: internal-consistency, communication, radiation, fermi-paradox

> - The [Fermi Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_paradox) contrasts the overwhelming lack of evidence of    alien life with the high theoretical probability of observable
>     alien    life.
> - Groups such as [SETI](http://www.seti.org/) observe incoming radiation from space to search    for signs of life outside Earth.
> - The [cosmic microwave background](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_microwave_background) radiation we observe is believed to have    resulted from the Big Bang.

**Could the cosmic microwave background be the result of an abundance of alien life communicating, thus solving the Fermi Paradox?**
*In other words, what evidence justifies or disproves the above statement?*

**If so, how would you explain the lack of leftover radiation from the Big Bang?**

Comment: If you think this is too broad or too opinion based please help me by editing it. I will accept all edits that help keep this answerable.

Comment: That doesn't explain why we don't see more obvious signs of them.  All it takes is one species in which even a tiny minority of individuals seek colonization for the species to spread galaxy wide in an eyeblink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to answer such questions, because there are so many unknowns.  I would point to the [Drake Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drake_equation) as an excellent example of the extremes one has to go to quantify such a discussion.  Many of the probabilities that make up the Drake Equation are truly unknowns.

However, the background radiation has a *very very* regular spectra.  It's a very easy to recognize spectra.  Because of that, it's trivial to analyze any signals from other sources and discern the difference between them and a background radiation.  We regularly do analyses in multiple spectral regions, making it trivial to isolate any non-background signals.  I would call it implausible that, out of all of the factors which go into the Drake Equation, background radiation would prove to be the straw that broke the camel's back.

As for your last question, abut explaining the radiation, that's a completely separate topic unrelated to Fermi or Drake, and a good topic for speculation in the physics community.  You may be able to succeed with a Physics.SE question on the topic, but do be sure to do a search first.  It's a popular topic, someone may have asked already!

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer! Could you disprove the "regular spectra" part by saying the radiation here may be different from the radiation somewhere else, and our neighborhood just has x channels? Or is there a way we can observe that it's the same everywhere?

Comment: By regular I mean the spectra is very well known (I'm pretty certain its blackbody, but I don't know for sure).  This means that if you see a certain amount of background radiation in the IR band, you can calculate the expected amount of radiation that a UV sensor would detect.  (although note: background radiation in those bands is REALLY low.  Most background radiation is in the longer RF bands).  As for detecting it everywhere, we've never flown anything to another star to check, but when we look in all directions, we see a *surprisingly* consistent temperature in all directions.

Comment: If radiation behaved differently in different parts of the visible universe, we'd almost certainly notice things that were strange and inexplicable. We can currently explain a great deal with our working assumption that the laws of physics are the same everywhere. That is an assumption, but it's held up well for all the time we've been doing spectroscopy.

Comment: @JohnDallman Not necessarily radiation behaving differently, just different types of radiation (radio here, x-ray here, visible light here, etc) from different communications, which would not interfere with the laws of physics

Comment: @Zxyrra We have no definitive way of scientifically proving that the radiation we see from the background radiation is not different a light year away.  However, we have absolutely no reason to believe this is the case.  In these situations, science shys away from such hypotheses as you put forth.  That's not to say its definitively wrong, its just a topic that science cannot touch.  It would also be an awefully mighty coincidence if we saw blackbody radiation (a very specific mix of radio, xray, visible, IR, etc.) here, and others saw something other than blackbody.

Comment: My thoughts were just that if it either could or could not be different farther away it was reasonable to postulate that it *might* be different. I wouldn't call it a coincidence that different places may have different radiation, I would call it evidence for or against a claim

Comment: @Zxyrra A skeptic, such as myself, would entertain such an idea as just that... an idea.  I might even go further and question what physical laws need to be revisited based on such an observation, if such an observation ever actually happened.  There's some interesting features deep in the bowels of science that are called into question.  I personally like the gentle reminder that I don't actually know everything, I just think I know everything.  However, nobody would consider it evidence of anything unless it was actually observed (or not observed).  That word has a different meaning.

Comment: The huge coincidence would be that this place where the Earth is sees blackbody in all directions, without much in the way of deviations. The major deviation from uniformity is symmetrical over the sky and consistent with a motion of our galaxy with respect to the background. The minor deviations have a complex structure that gives us clues about the nature of the universe which are consistent with other observations and theories. My opinion is that if this is not natural, it is being deliberately faked.

Answer (score 2):

The simplistic answer would be, and this is the type of answer that easily falls over in contact with any real depth of knowledge, that was no Big Bang, and therefore, no cosmic microwave background (CMB) radiation produced as a relic.

if we were living in a Big Bang free universe this could extend infinitely in all directions of space and time. Electromagnetic radiation from all sources, not just alien civilizations, but stars, galaxies and astrophysical whatever, could have eventually mushed together into what resembles the CMB.

For good measure, the old hypothesis of "tired photons" could be tossed into the mix. In this case, assume the photons wind over time as they travel cosmological distances to a  base energy level of microwave radiation photons.

An answer of this sort could pass the this is plausible enough for a certain type of science fiction story. It's doubtful if it could pass the reality test of science as she is practised in the real world.